# Tiny MCE 5: keep source code in the original pasted format

Tags: html, tinymce-5

I use Tiny MCE 5 as a page editor for my website. I'm having a small problem: Tiny MCE's source code editor restructures the original pasted code, which adds unwanted spaces when the page is displayed on my site.

Here's an example (original source code created):

```
<div class="h1">La route peut-être longue pour <h1 style="display: inline;">solutionner les <span class="text-gradient_inverse">problèmes de santé</span></h1>, Ludovic vous accompagne dans ce programme vidéo.</div>
```

Here's the Tiny rendering after clicking on the button to save the source code:

```
<div class="h1">La route peut-être longue pour 
<h1 style="display: inline;">solutionner les <span class="text-gradient_inverse">problèmes de santé</span></h1>
, Ludovic vous accompagne dans ce programme vidéo.</div>
```

In fact, Tiny MCE lines up the H1 tag, which adds extra white space to the display (rendered on my site): "La route peut-être longue pour solutionner les problèmes de santé , Ludovic vous accompagne dans ce programme vidéo." ==> Extra space before the coma.

I'd like to be able to deactivate source code restructuring so as to keep the code initially pasted and reflected in the same structure (without line breaks).

The HTML example above comes from a company that specializes in Search Engine Optimization (SEO) to optimize the H1 tag for important keywords while maintaining a visually more important title.

I'm still using Tiny MCE 5 because this version's api gives me more flexibility than the last version (especially when it comes to creating in-house plugins).

Do you have any ideas on how to do this?